# Karma : Unable to start chrome via remote webdriver failed after 2 times

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, karma-runner

Working with an angular 7 project which basically runs inside a docker container . When i tried running ng test inside the container . I got this issue :

```
26 11 2019 12:14:08.572:ERROR [WebDriver]: WebDriver command failed { spec:
   { platform: 'ANY',
     testName: 'Karma test',
     tags: [],
     version: '',
     browserName: 'chrome',
     base: 'WebDriver',
     flags: [ '--no-sandbox' ] },
  error: {"message":"[get(\"http://app:9876/?id=89494442\")] Unexpected data in simpleCallback.","data":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n\n<!--//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n//\n//    Copyright (c) 1996 - 2015, Websense, Inc.    All Rights Reserved\n//    See WebsenseCopyright.txt for copyright information\n//\n///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////... }
```

**Karma server got started . But it is failing to launch chrome webdriver.**

Finally the process stopped with this error message :

*chrome via Remote WebDriver failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.*

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes actually our company uses proxy for applications. When i try to run our application it was running in our network and karma was basically trying hit our application which was not in our network and therefore  blocked. That was the main issue.

Comment: Can you please share your complete configuration, in my case we are using jenkins pod template to create selenium chrome container. Karma launcher will be using this chrome container to run test cases. My setup is completely working fine with karma-selenium-webdriver-launcher, but this plugin in very old, so planning to replace it with karma-webdriver-launcher and selenium-driver.